# ExtJs 6.2.1 classic restrain POST function from RoweditPlugin

Tags: overriding, extjs6, extjs6-classic, roweditor

i created a basic sencha project via cmd:

`sencha -sdk path/to/SDK generate app classic SandBox path/to/TARGET`

in addition i changed the the data to a **Personel.json**

```
{ "items": [
{ "name": "Jean Luc", "email": "jeanluc.picard@enterprise.com", "phone": "555-111-1111" },
{ "name": "Worf",     "email": "worf.moghsson@enterprise.com",  "phone": "555-222-2222" },
{ "name": "Deanna",   "email": "deanna.troi@enterprise.com",    "phone": "555-333-3333" },
{ "name": "Data",     "email": "mr.data@enterprise.com",        "phone": "555-444-4444" }]}
```

**store.Personnel.js**

```
Ext.define('SandBox.store.Personnel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
alias: 'store.personnel',
autoLoad: true,
autoSync: true,
loading: true,

model: 'SandBox.model.Personnel',

proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'resources/json/Personnel.json',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'items'
    }
}
});
```

now i want to edit the values inside the table with the rowediting plugin.
**view.main.List.js**

```
Ext.define('SandBox.view.main.List',{
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
xtype: 'mainlist',
requires: [
    'SandBox.store.Personnel'
],
title: 'Personnel',
store: {
    type: 'personnel'
},    
plugins: {
    ptype: 'rowediting'
},    
columns: [{  
        text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name', 
        editor:{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            emptyText: 'Name'
     }},{ 
        text: 'Email', 
        dataIndex: 'email', 
        flex: 1,
        editor:{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            emptyText: 'Email' 
     }},{ 
        text: 'Phone', 
        dataIndex: 'phone', 
        flex: 1 ,
        editor:{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            emptyText: 'Phone'
     }}
]});
```

if i try to change any value of the table always the first entry of the Personnel.json will insert in the whole row. so i try to disable the POST function from the update button and keep the changed data localy in cause i haven't actualy any backend. later i want to send explicit the POST request by a seperate "Send" button. i tried to customize the rowediting plugin like [this](https://github.com/jnesislabs/rowediting/blob/master/app/view/main/List.js) in addition i changed the autoCancel in autoUpdate.

```
rowediting: {
            clicksToMoveEditor: 1,
            autoUpdate: false,
            useButtonText: false,
            saveBtnIconCls: 'fa fa-check green-color',
            cancelBtnIconCls: 'fa fa-times red-color'
        }
```

this way i get the following error:

```
Error: [Ext.createByAlias] Unrecognized alias: plugin.null ext-all-rtl-debug.js:15041:27
instantiateByAlias
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:15041:27
create
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:241654:26
constructPlugin
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:70680:26
constructPlugins
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:70708:33
initComponent
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:200605:26
callParent
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:12525:20
initComponent
http://localhost:1841/ext/classic/theme-neptune/overrides/panel/Table.js:9:9
constructor
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:67285:9
callParent
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:12525:20
constructor
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:200554:9
constructor
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:13168:20
widget
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:15582:20
create
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:27456:16
lookupComponent
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:140073:20
prepareItems
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:140658:32
add
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:139552:23
initItems
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:139975:17
callParent
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:12525:20
initItems
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:161148:9
initComponent
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:139936:9
callParent
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:12525:20
initComponent
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:161137:9
constructor
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:67285:9
constructor
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:13168:20
widget
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:15582:20
create
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:27456:16
lookupComponent
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:140073:20
prepareItems
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:140658:32
add
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:139552:23
initItems
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:139975:17
callParent
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:12525:20
initItems
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:161148:9
initComponent
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:139936:9
callParent
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:12525:20
initComponent
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:161137:9
callParent
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:12525:20
initComponent
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:247719:9
constructor
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:67285:9
constructor
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:13168:20
anonymous
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:3:8
create
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:15525:20
create
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:11458:20
applyMainView
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:96557:16
setter
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:10577:57
makeInitGetter/<
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:10556:24
initMainView
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:96329:13
onBeforeLaunch
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:96283:9
callParent
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:12525:20
onBeforeLaunch
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:96585:9
onProfilesReady
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:96217:9
constructor
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:96186:9
constructor
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:13168:20
createApp/<
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:96483:48
invoke
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:18581:17
doInvokeAll
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:18625:13
invokeAll
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:18594:13
handleReady
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:18550:13
handleReadySoon/me.timer<
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:18565:17
bind/<
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:6891:28
defer/<
http://localhost:1841/ext/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js:7088:29
```

so i tried to override the plugin like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30844617/adding-new-button-save-and-next-apart-from-update-and-cancel-given-in-the-edit) an add a new **RoweditPlugin.js**

```
Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditorButtons.override({
constructor: function(config)
{
    var me = this,
    rowEditor = config.rowEditor,
    editPlugin = rowEditor.editingPlugin;

    me.callParent(arguments);
    me.insert(0,
    {
        cls: Ext.baseCSSPrefis + 'row-editor-update-button',
        itemId: 'nbtn',
        handler: editPlugin.newSave,
        text: 'Update Local',
        disabled: rowEditor.updateButtonDisabled
    });
},
newSave: function(button)
{
    this.completeEdit();
}
});
```

and changed the call from the plugin in List.js

```
plugins: {
    ptype: 'rowediting',
    autoUpdate: false
},
```

but now the rowEditPlugin is uneffected by my override. what can i do to change the default functionallity from the update button?